# Is it possible to create a catalog price rule based on the range of a date?

Tags: catalog-price-rules

Given an attribute of type `Date`, I know it's possible to create a catalog price rule based on math (=, >, <) for a given date. What I'm seeing if anyone knows about, is if it's possible to create one based on compound math.

**Example**
Attribute: `Custom Date`

Catalog Price rule:
`Custom Date` <= 30 days < `Custom Date`

so given today is `2014-12-15` , the rule would apply all products with a `Custom Date` of 2014-11-15 or earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. It only accepts a fixed date as input. To change this would require overwriting the logic of the promotional rules models